# choose all except fixed columns Power Query (Excel)

Tags: excel, powerquery

Lets say that I have a table in Power Query where the number of columns is not fixed (it varies depending on the data that I get from database).

The issue is that I want to fill down values later on, for which I have a code like

Table.FillDown(#"Razvrščene vrstice",{"Column2", "Column3", "Column4", "Column5", "Column6", "Column7", "Column8", "Column9", "Column10"})

Of course when I get lets say one column less, the whole thing crashes ('Cannot find column Column10')...

Is there any way around this? For example: 'choose all but the first two columns and fill them down'?

Thanks,
Matija

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this help?

If I start with this table, named Table1:

[image]

And I use the following query:

```
let
Source = Table1,
#"Filled Down" = Table.FillDown(Source,List.RemoveMatchingItems(Table.ColumnNames(Source),{"Column1", "Column2"}))
in
#"Filled Down"
```

I get this:

[image]

The `{"Column1", "Column2"}` are the names of the columns to be skipped during the filldown.

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I needed! I was already trying to make things work with dummy columns, but this is way more exact... Thanks again!